# make api call only after state has been updated by another api call

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx

I am currently building an angular application using ngrx.
I need to call api2 and api3 only after the response for api1 has been updated in that state.

I am getting the response of api1 by using a selector like this: this.service.getIsLoadedValue$.

This will return a boolean observable.

What I need to achieve is that I want to make the following API calls only after the state of the isLoaded flag has been updated to true.

```
 return this.method
      .getData({
        param:  param1
    
      })
      .pipe(
        switchMap(res =>
          this.method
            .getMoreData({
              param: res,
             
            })
            .pipe(
              tap(response => {
                console.log(response)
              })
            )
        )
      );
```

I know i need to filter on the isloaded flag but i am having a tough time integrating this.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: use a different effect ?